# htaccess doesn't allow my domain

Tags: .htaccess, directadmin

I created a htaccess file and put it in public_html directory(root of my server):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mdpcomics.ir/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://blogvault.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/no-hotlinking.png [NC,R,L]
</ifModule>
```

it blocks hotlinking and shows another image. but it doesn't allow my own domain too.

i.e. this link should not show the image:
http://dl.mdpcomics.ir/logo.png

but this link should show it. I mean I want it to show the image by using this link:
http://mdpcomics.ir/?imagename=logo

but it won't allow that too.

I already searched everywhere and I tried so many suggestions but all of them worked as follow:

> 1. everyone can see images
> 2. no one can see images including myself O.o

my server os is linux and my panel is directadmin

Edit: 
I realized that my host has a fake or invalid ip: 178.63.56.20320
I got that ip by php code:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your problem: In your `RewriteRule` it says `https://`, but your `RewriteCond` is testing for `http://`. You can make it test for both by simply adding `s?`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://mdpcomics.ir/.*$ [NC]
```

Further things to be aware of:

- clients won't send the `Referer` in a non-HTTPS request if the request originated from an HTTPS location
- some clients never send the `Referer` header or set it to something totally different in order to protect their privacy

To catch these cases I would add another condition:

```
# Assume client sent "real" Referer if it begins with http(s)://
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:// [NC]
```

The downside is, images can be hotlinked from foreign HTTPS locations if your site is running normal HTTP.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but nope, didn't help either, RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?:// [NC] makes the hotlinking available for everyone, and the first one still doesn't allow me to see pictures with my own domain,

Comment: @MDP Very strange, I do not know why the REMOTE_ADDR is so garbled. Do your requests even include the Referer header? Test by linking from one file `test.html`: `<a href="test.php">test</a>` to another `test.php`: `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>`